# What is the proper java app directory structure with Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I started to learn JSP and Tomcat Container, and I know how the directories must be stored, but I'm confused by several things:

1. If we use only web app, why do we need the rest of the folders here? (highlighted blue). Can I just delete them and load my project with "web" as root?
   [image]

2. How can I initialize Gradle/Maven or use any other framework inside Tomcat web application? (e.g Where to put pom.xml file?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The folder `.idea` and the file `Tomcat-web-app.iml` are necessary for your IDE, configuration is stored there. If you delete them the project will fall apart in your IDE. You can delete the `src` folder as long as you're not using it.
2. `pom.xml` should be put on the root level of your project, so right under `Tomcat-web-app/`. Afterwards you can initialize it as a Maven project by adding framework support for Maven - right click on your project (`Tomcat-web-app`) and you should see it there. Refer to [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/convert-a-regular-project-into-a-maven-project.html) if you're having issues. It is much more straight forward however to just create a Maven project from scratch and then copy in your web files.

Comment: No problem.. I've added a guide if you need more details about the Maven initialization: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/convert-a-regular-project-into-a-maven-project.html